# how to change TabBarItens when push a UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

On my `firstViewController` I have a `tabbar` that contains my `firstViewController` and a `helpViewController`.

When I click on a button from the `FirstViewController`, I push a `NewViewController`. But, when this view is pushed, I want to change the content from the `TabBarController` to display other ViewControllers, like `infoViewController`, `optionViewController` and `NewViewController`. Is that possible?

The First Image represents my application. The `FirstViewController` has a button that will push the `NewViewController`. When the user clicks this button, I want that my app shows what is in the second image. Is possible?[image: My problem]

Answer (score 1):

You should only have 1 `UITabBarController` in a project, and it should be your rootViewController. If you want different tabs then you should explore `setViewControllers:animated:`.

Comment: But how do I change the tabs that will appear on the 'UITabBarController'? I mean, what code I should put on my  'NewViewController'?

Comment: each `UIViewController` is responsible for providing his tab. So when you set the viewControllers, the tabs will fill in. Your question is very unclear with regards to `FirstViewController` and `NewViewController`. Are they in a `UINavigationController` and you basically want `FirstViewController` to push to the `UITabBarController` with `NewViewController` as the first view?

Comment: I have as rootViewController the `FirstViewController`. This view has a `NavigationController` and a `TabBarController` showing itself and a HelpViewController. When I click on a button, the app push the `NewViewController`. On this ViewController, I want to change the `TabBarController` to show itself, `InfoViewController` and `optionsViewController`.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand. `UITabBarController` should be your root object if you have one, it should not be embedded in a `UINavigationController`.  It sounds like you want a `UINavigationController` that contains two `UITabBarController` view Controllers, each with their own tabs. Pushing from one `VC` to another but stating that they have the same `TabBarController` doesn't make any sense to me. Sorry.